# ggsankey: Labels and nodes do not have same position in the output

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, nodes, sankey-diagram

Aiming for a sankey without NA-nodes, I adapted my code according to the recommendations in this post:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141362/how-to-skip-nodes-with-na-value-in-ggsankey)

In my output, the number and the position of the labels do not match the corresponding nodes.

Questions:

- How to fix this and why does this occur?
  -- are positions (aes?) of nodes an labels are calculated separately?
- Generally: how can I check and/or change x&y values (aes?) in e.g. geom_sankey_text() or geom_sankey_label()?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
size<-20
df<-data.frame(id=1:size,
               Inclusion=sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), size, replace=T),
               t1=sample(c("Drug1","Drug2", NA), size, replace=T, prob = c(0.3,0.5, 0.2)),
               t2=sample(c("otherTherapy1", "otherTherapy2", NA), size, replace=T, prob = c(0.2,0.3, 0.5)), 
               outcome=sample(c("Dead","Or", "Alive"), size, replace=T, prob = c(0.3,0.38,0.32)))

do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x[-1])
  data.frame(x = names(x), node = x, 
             next_x = dplyr::lead(names(x)), 
             next_node = dplyr::lead(x), row.names = NULL)
})) %>%  mutate(x = factor(x, names(df)[-1]),
                next_x = factor(next_x, names(df)[-1])) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = x,
              next_x = next_x,
              node = node,
              next_node = next_node,
              fill = node,
              label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5,
              node.color = NA,
              show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_sankey_text(size = 3, color = "black", fill = NA, hjust = 0, 
                   position = position_nudge(x = 0.1))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

'''
here is the ouput:
[image]

I have not found an explanation for this in the archive here and in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a similar problem. I found that including the "group" clause in the geom_sankey_label fixed this problem!

For example, in your code using this should work

geom_sankey_text(aes(group = node, label = node), size = 3, color = "black",fill = NA, hjust = 0, position = position_nudge(x = 0.1))

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, definitely, there is an improvement in the result, but still some labels are doubled and in the wrong position in my tests.